# control windows right click context menu for file folder using java

Tags: java, windows, access-rights

how to control windows right click context menu for file folder using java, Is there any possibility for doing this using java. i want that if user create/edit/delete any file/folder   in given/specific folder before that operation my java program get the user's action and allow or dis-allow user for doing that.

Please help me how can i do that, doing R&D for that but not found any solution yet. need some guide line for how to achieve this if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Is there any possibility for doing this using java."*  Well if you mean 'control by `Robot`' then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @AndrewThompson no, not using Robot, i wanted that when user comes to a given folder and try to create any file/folder into that folder then my java program get its action